# Regex if or else

Tags: php, regex, if-statement, pcre

Currently I have 2 types of lines in my logs, and using regex I want to select one type and the other type I need to discard.

If I am getting a log line, with hostname after the timestamp, then I want to select it.
The hostname pattern will always be the same (like, `aabvabcw74.def.co.uk`, `aaxptac103.def.co.uk`, etc). 
E.g.:

> 2017-04-24T09:20:01.687387+00:00 aabvabcw74.def.co.uk hostd-probe:

Anything other than this pattern and I want to discard the line, like in the following examples:

> 2017-04-14T15:18:34.727042+00:00 **Fri Apr 14 15:18:34 2017** aalesxbs029.def.co.uk lacp: DEBUG]:147, Recv signal 15, LACP service is about to stop

-- It has 2 timestamps so I want to discard this log line

> 2017-04-24T09:20:01.687387+00:00 **hostd probing is done.** aabvabcw74.def.co.uk hostd-probe:

--- here hostd is coming as the hostname, which is wrong so I want to discard this log line as well

> 2017-04-24T20:53:29.334348+00:00 **10.199.6.5** .def.co.uk aabvabcs15.def.co.uk Fdm: sslThumbprint>95:43:64:71:A3:60:D8:17:C8:6F:68:83:92:CE:E4:3B:53:4E:1D:AD10.199.6.5a2:0e:09:01:0a:00a2:0e:09:01:0b:01/vmfs/volumes/b01f388c-aaa4889f/vmfs/volumes/6ad2d8d7-86746df14435.5.03568722host-619286aabvabcs16.def.co.uk

---- here I am getting an ip address after the timestamp so I want to discard this line as well

Please help me with a solution

Comment: Formatted to make the examples clearer, and changed some grammar/wording to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
^\d+-\d+-\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+\+\d{2}:\d{2}\s(?:aabvabcw74|aaxptac103).def.co.uk
```

with flags `g` and `m`

or, if you don't care about timestamp format, then simpler:

```
^[\dT:\.+-]+\s(?:aabvabcw74|aaxptac103).def.co.uk
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BX6Pwp/2)